# Name that group! Generalization of $A(p)$ for abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, torsion-groups

Have you seen or heard of the groups $\mathcal{A}(n)$ or $A(n)$ (for any integer $n$) described below?

*This is the well-known construction*: 
Let $A$ be an abelian group.  Then $A(p)$ is a subgroup which is the set of all elements $x\in A$ such that $ord(x) = p^k \ $ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.  This, for prime $p$ that is, is a known construction talked about in Lang's Algebra.  And if $A$ is torsion it's isomorphic to a direct sum of its nonzero $A(p)$ subgroups.  Knowing that, what about $A(n)$ for any integer $n$?  Let's see...

*Here's the new construction that I'm wondering about:* 
Define $\mathcal{A}(n)$ to be the set of all elements that have an order that is a divisor of $n$.  Then $\mathcal{A}(n)$ is a group.

Proof: If $x \in \mathcal{A}(n)$, then $dx = 0 \implies 0 = d(-x). \ $  But $\forall m : mx = 0, ord(x) \mid m$, so $ord(-x) \mid d \mid n$, so $ord(-x) \mid n$.  If $x, y \in \mathcal{A}(n)$, let $ord(x) = e, ord(y) = e$; let $c = lcm(d,e)$.  Then $c(x+y) = 0$.  But notice that any divisor of $lcd(d,e)$ divides $n$.  So $x+y \in \mathcal{A}(n)$. QED.

Then the $A(p) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mathcal{A}(p^k) = \cup_k \mathcal{A}(p^k). \ $  That works for prime $p$, but also for any integer $n$.  I.o.w. $A(n)$ is also a group.

What do you guys think?

Comment: What is the question? What I think (assuming I'm a guy)? That would seem to fall under "too broad to be answered".

Comment: I added an intro

Comment: The question has become somewhat confused, since you now have conflicting definitions of $A(n)$ when $n$ happens to be prime (one of them used to be called $A'(n)$, which was better). I suppose the question is about $\bigcup_k A'(n^k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $A(p)$ is the [$p$-power torsion subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup#p-power_torsion_subgroups) of $A$, and $A(n)$ is the direct sum of all subgroups $A(p)$ where $p$ runs through the prime factors of$~n$.

Answer (score 1):

The subgroup you denote as $\mathcal{A}(n)$ - consisting of all the elements of $A$ whose order divides $n$ -  is often denoted $A[n]$ and is known as the **$n$-torsion subgroup of $A$**. Note that this terminology **does not coincide** with the common use of "$p$-torsion" to mean "$p$-power torsion" when $p$ is a prime number. This terminology **is**, however, a correct usage of the general case where an element $m$ of an $R$-module $M$ is referred to as $r$-torsion when $rm=0$.

The subset  consisting of all the elements of $A$ whose order is a power of $n$ is not a subgroup of $A$ unless $n$ is prime. Otherwise there is a power of $n$ with a divisor that is not a power of $n$, and hence an element of $A(n)$ with a multiple that is not an element of $A(n)$.

The subset consisting of all the elements of $A$ whose order is a **divisor** of a power of $n$ is just the span of the subgroups $A(p)$ as $p$ ranges over the divisors of $n$, or in other words, the subgroup
$$\sum_{p\mid n}A(p)$$
As far as I know there is no separate name for this subgroup.